# Composite C1 site with MVC Player - not returning 404 on non-existent pages

Tags: c1-cms

I'm using MVC Player with a Composite C1 site - instead of returning a 404 on all made up non-existent pages it returns:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: filePath
```

How can I get it to return a 404 instead? (this is very important for Google Indexing).

Comment: Something is not adding up... The player is only invoked if the page the urls corresponds to is found. Sounds to me that the page does indeed exist but that your player is pointing to a non-existing view, controller or action.

Comment: I can invent any page name - it comes up with that same error.

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing the terms. The page you have inserted the player on, is the actual page. That can not be non-existing. Lets say that page has a path of /MyPage. Now, if you write /MyPage/MySecondPage in your browser, that will be resolved to /MyPage and MySecondPage is stored in a variable which you can query. That means that your player added to MyPage will get executed for /MyPage/MySecondPage as well, even though in your mind its a non-existing page. Does it make sense?